# Getting type error while running react app, TypeError: instance.render is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-dom

[click here for error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5yb6.png)
i am new to react and i am just trying to displaying registration form in react and it shows type error while ruuning app on browser and i dont know how to fix it .

my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import Register from './components/Register'

function App () {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Register />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Register extends Component {
  
  regsister () {
    alert('register')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>

        <div>
          <input type='text' /><br /><br />
          <input type='text' /><br /><br />
          <button onclick={() => this.register()}>Register</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Component
```

i would really appreciate some answers
Thanks for help

Comment: Where are you attaching your app to the DOM with ReactDOM.render()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `export default Component`.

Export your register component properly. Not the `React` library `Component`

```js
export default Register
```

Comment: yes issue resolved  thanks for the help its working now.